# choosing the right value to calculate a probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A lot of $n$ itms contains $k$ defectives, and $m$ are selected randomly and inspected. How should the value of $m$ be chosen so that the probability that at least one defective item turns up is 0.90?

Attempt:

So thinking about it i figured it would be easier to figure out the complement of this thus $1 - p(A^c)$ where A = event.

As such:  $$1 - \frac {{n-k\choose m}{k\choose 0}}{{n\choose m}} $$

But now i am having an issue in getting rid of some of the factorials. Suggestions? Did i interpret it right?

Comment: You Interpret it right. The only real simplification  I see is ${k \choose 0}=1$.

Comment: But how could i solve for the $m$ ? Because i see no simple expression for it Considerin i write the "choose" expressions in their factorial form

Comment: Just wait a few minutes and somebody will help you. At the moment I don´t see a way to solve the eqution for m.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo. Ok thanks

Comment: @dc3rd: OK. New Answer posted. Seems better. Comments welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analytic  solution  to the exact hypergeometric
seems messy.
Some simplifications is possible if you express
the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials: to begin,
two factors $m!$ cancel. You might be able to use Sterling's formula for an approximation to the rest, but that formula works best for large values, and I'm not sure how accurate the result would be in your case.

The exact quantity you show in your question is $P(X = 0),$ where $X$ has a hypergeometric distribution based selecting $m$ items without replacement from a population of $n$ items of which $k$ are defective. Using $p = k/n,$, the mean of this distribution is $\mu = mp,$ and standard deviation

$$\sigma = \sqrt{mp(1-p)\frac{n-m}{n-1}}.$$

For $m$ sufficiently large and $p$ not too close to 0 or 1,
$X$ has approximately a normal distribution with mean $\mu$
and SD $\sigma.$ So we seek $m$ just large enough that
$$P(X = 0) = P(X \le 0.5) \approx P(Z \le (0.5 - \mu)/\sigma) = .9.$$
Thus we could solve $(0.5 - \mu)/\sigma = 1.28$ for $m$ in terms of $k$ and $n$ when $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are expressed in terms of $m, n,$ and $k.$

*Example:* Letting $n = 100$ and $k = 5$ we use computations in R to find the exact value $m = 37$ from the hyergeometric distribution and the approximate value $m = 38$ from the normal approximation. We also illustrate that a binomial model with $m$ trials and probability $p$ of a defective on each draw (sampling *with* replacement) does not give a good value of $m$ in this example.

```
 n = 100;  k = 5;  p = k/n;  m=1:(n-1)
 mu = m*p;  sd = sqrt(m*p*(1-p)*(n-m)/(n-1))
 # Normal approximation
 nor = 1 - pnorm(0.5, mu, sd)
 min(m[nor >= .9])
 ## 38

 # Exact hypergeometric computation
 hyp = 1 - dhyper(0, k, n-5, m)
 min(m[hyp >= .9])
 ## 37

 # Binomial approximation (unsatisfactory for this n and k)
 bin = 1 - dbinom(0, m, k/n)
 min(m[bin >= .9])
 ## 45
```

When the lot size is large enough that $m$ turns out to be very much smaller than $n,$ then the binomial works well. For example,
with $n = 1000$ and $k=200,$ the exact hypergeometric value
is $m = 13$ and both the normal and the binomial approximations
give $m = 11.$

The binomial approximation has the advantage
that it is very easy to solve $(1 - k/n)^m \approx 0.1$ for $m$ in terms of
$k$ and $n.$

Comment: Very insightful solution actually, it highlights the fact that to obtain an exact solution we may need the help of a computer unless one is willing to slave away for an extremely long time applying estimation methods. I then wonder why would an undergrad text ask me that sort of question in the first chapter if it is not at as easy as it sounds?

Comment: @dc3rd.  My guess: Author had the binomial approx. in mind, but gave insufficient thought to how it could go wrong. I say this having written a few naive questions of my own. And there's always the possibility we're overlooking something.